# Copying from string to string and pasting in new file

Tags: c#, c++, c

The question i have is the following..

I have a texture file, it cannot be opened with any texture editor in the world, that file holds for example 100 textures. The only way to grab those textures is to open the file with a Hex Editor (Hex Workshop for example) and find "GBIX" strings. when you find a "GBIX" string you start to copy from there till the very start of another GBIX, you create a new file, paste it there, save it as PVR and there you have the texture. However you need to do that 100 times because the file has 100 "GBIX" string (100 textures). Well, now, i have some minor skills at programming, in C# specially, but i have no idea how to create a program that would copy from string to string and then save it in a new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have used C#. This should give you a rough idea of how you could do this in C#, although I haven't tested it myself.

Before you start, how big is your file? If it can fit entirely in memory, the easiest way to read it is to use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx), which will read the entire file into one great big array of bytes. (If your file is gigabytes in size you won't be able to load it all at once. If that's the case there are more advanced ways to read the file, but I'll not move on to those just yet.)

You can use [`File.ReadAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) to read the file, [`Array.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01h9de4t.aspx) to search inside it for the byte 'G', and normal array indexing to check for the other letters. When you find them, you can copy out a chunk of the array using [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx) and save it to a file using [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx).

Your question isn't entirely clear about the format of the file. From your description, I think it's something like this:

```
HEADERBYTESblahblahblahGBIXcontentcontentcontentGBIXmorecontentGBIXyetmorecontent
```

and you expect this to be discarded:

```
HEADERBYTESblahblahblah
```

and three separate files to be created:

```
GBIXcontentcontentcontent
GBIXmorecontent
GBIXyetmorecontent
```

So I'm assuming that there might be text before the first "GBIX" and you want to ignore it, and that from the last "GBIX" to the end of the file is a proper texture that you want to extract, with nothing coming after it. I'm also assuming that the characters "GBIX" never occur in the middle of one of the textures - if they do then you will need to use something that can actually understand the file format.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void WriteFile(int aFileIndex, byte[] sourceBytes, int firstByteIndex, int byteCount)
    {
        string filename = String.Format("output{0}.pvr", aFileIndex);
        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[byteCount];
        Array.Copy(sourceBytes, firstByteIndex, outputBytes, 0, byteCount);
        File.WriteAllBytes(filename, outputBytes);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("inputfile");
        int filesOutput = 0;
        int startIndex = -1;
        int currentIndex = 0;
        for (;;)
        {
            int nextIndex = Array.IndexOf(fileBytes, (byte)'G', currentIndex);
            if (nextIndex == -1)
            {
                // There are no more ASCII 'G's in the file.
                break;
            }
            if (nextIndex + 4 >= fileBytes.Length)
            {
                // There aren't enough characters left in the file for this
                // to be an ASCII "GBIX" string.
                break;
            }
            if (fileBytes[nextIndex+1] == (byte)'B' &&
                fileBytes[nextIndex+2] == (byte)'I' &&
                fileBytes[nextIndex+3] == (byte)'X')
            {
                // Found ASCII "GBIX" at nextIndex. Output the previous
                // complete file, if there is one.
                if (startIndex != -1)
                {
                    Write(filesOutput, fileBytes, startIndex, nextIndex - startIndex);
                }
                filesOutput += 1;
                startIndex = nextIndex;
            }
            currentIndex = nextIndex + 1;
        }
        if (startIndex != -1)
        {
            WriteFile(filesOutput, fileBytes, startIndex, fileBytes.Length - startIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, this would be quite trivial:

1. Load the file into memory
2. Loop trough, using `strstr()` to look for the `GBIX` pattern
3. For each found pattern, look for the next one (or end of file)
4. For each found end, write out the range between to a new binary file

I imagine it would be even easier in higher-level languages. :)

What is your question?

Comment: Well, my question is...
1 - How to load files into memory in C?
2 - How to do steps 3 and 4?
3 - God i really need to take a real course in programming

Answer (score 1):

Can you program in C.
Then just do following things

```
1.open the file using `fopen()` in binary mode.
2.use a loop upto the end of file and search for the string what you want (strstr() to look for the GBIX pattern)-copied from unwind 
3.Then after finding each pattern get the position of the file pointer using ftell() and store it to a array of 100 integer(as 100 of texture you have ).
4.Then go to the first byte of file by using fseek().
5.Now you can use your array to find the location and read the whole data up to the next array element (do it in a loop upto 100 times).
6.then store this data or write it to another file(open a file in append mode and write there).
```

I think little bit tricky but use this algorithm and search for the code from the internet you will definitely able do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code example might help you. It shows how to parse a file for you. All you will need to do is create a new file..

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Extensions;
using System.Drawing;

/* Archive Module */
namespace puyo_tools
{
    public class Images
    {
        /* Image format */
        private ImageClass Converter = null;
        public GraphicFormat Format  = GraphicFormat.NULL;
        private Stream Data          = null;
        private Bitmap imageData     = null;
        public string ImageName      = null;
        private string FileExt       = null;

        /* Image Object for unpacking */
        public Images(Stream dataStream, string dataFilename)
        {
            /* Set up our image information */
            Data = dataStream;

            ImageInformation(ref Data, out Format, out Converter, out ImageName, out FileExt);
        }

        /* Unpack image */
        public Bitmap Unpack()
        {
            return Converter.Unpack(ref Data);
        }
        public Bitmap Unpack(Stream palette)
        {
            return Converter.Unpack(ref Data, palette);
        }

        /* Pack image */
        public Stream Pack()
        {
            return Converter.Pack(ref imageData);
        }

        /* Output Directory */
        public string OutputDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                return (ImageName == null ? null : ImageName + " Converted");
            }
        }

        /* File Extension */
        public string FileExtension
        {
            get
            {
                return (FileExt == null ? String.Empty : FileExt);
            }
        }

        /* Get image information */
        private void ImageInformation(ref Stream data, out GraphicFormat format, out ImageClass converter, out string name, out string ext)
        {
            try
            {
                /* Let's check for image formats based on the 12 byte headers first */
                switch (data.ReadString(0x0, 12, false))
                {
                    case GraphicHeader.GIM: // GIM (Big Endian)
                    case GraphicHeader.MIG: // GIM (Little Endian)
                        format    = GraphicFormat.GIM;
                        converter = new GIM();
                        name      = "GIM";
                        ext       = ".gim";
                        return;
                }

                /* Ok, do special checks now */

                /* PVR file */
                if ((data.ReadString(0x0, 4) == GraphicHeader.GBIX && data.ReadString(0x10, 4) == GraphicHeader.PVRT && data.ReadByte(0x19) < 64) ||
                    (data.ReadString(0x0, 4) == GraphicHeader.PVRT && data.ReadByte(0x9) < 64))
                {
                    format    = GraphicFormat.PVR;
                    //converter = new PVR();
                    converter = null;
                    name      = "PVR";
                    ext       = ".pvr";
                    return;
                }

                /* GVR File */
                if ((data.ReadString(0x0, 4) == GraphicHeader.GBIX && data.ReadString(0x10, 4) == GraphicHeader.GVRT) ||
                    (data.ReadString(0x0, 4) == GraphicHeader.GCIX && data.ReadString(0x10, 4) == GraphicHeader.GVRT) ||
                    (data.ReadString(0x0, 4) == GraphicHeader.GVRT))
                {
                    format    = GraphicFormat.GVR;
                    converter = new GVR();
                    name      = "GVR";
                    ext       = ".gvr";
                    return;
                }

                /* SVR File */
                if ((data.ReadString(0x0, 4) == GraphicHeader.GBIX && data.ReadString(0x10, 4) == GraphicHeader.PVRT && data.ReadByte(0x19) > 64) ||
                    (data.ReadString(0x0, 4) == GraphicHeader.PVRT && data.ReadByte(0x9) > 64))
                {
                    format    = GraphicFormat.SVR;
                    converter = new SVR();
                    name      = "SVR";
                    ext       = ".svr";
                    return;
                }

                /* GMP File */
                if (data.ReadString(0x0, 8, false) == "GMP-200\x00")
                {
                    format    = GraphicFormat.GMP;
                    converter = new GMP();
                    name      = "GMP";
                    ext       = ".gmp";
                    return;
                }

                /* Unknown or unsupported compression */
                throw new GraphicFormatNotSupported();
            }
            catch (GraphicFormatNotSupported)
            {
                /* Unknown or unsupported image format */
                format     = GraphicFormat.NULL;
                converter  = null;
                name       = null;
                ext        = null;
                return;
            }
            catch
            {
                /* An error occured. */
                format     = GraphicFormat.NULL;
                converter  = null;
                name       = null;
                ext        = null;
                return;
            }
        }

        /* Image Information */
        public class Information
        {
            public string Name = null;
            public string Ext = null;
            public string Filter = null;

            public bool Unpack = false;
            public bool Pack  = false;

            public Information(string name, bool unpack, bool pack, string ext, string filter)
            {
                Name   = name;
                Ext    = ext;
                Filter = filter;

                Unpack = unpack;
                Pack   = pack;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Image Format */
    public enum GraphicFormat : byte
    {
        NULL,
        GIM,
        GMP,
        GVR,
        PVR,
        SVR,
    }

    /* Image Header */
    public static class GraphicHeader
    {
        public const string
            GBIX = "GBIX",
            GCIX = "GCIX",
            GIM  = ".GIM1.00\x00PSP",
            GMP  = "GMP-200\x00",
            GVRT = "GVRT",
            MIG  = "MIG.00.1PSP\x00",
            PVRT = "PVRT";
    }

    public abstract class ImageClass
    {
        /* Image Functions */
        public abstract Bitmap Unpack(ref Stream data);   // Unpack image
        public abstract Stream Pack(ref Bitmap data);     // Pack Image
        public abstract bool Check(ref Stream data);      // Check Image
        public abstract Images.Information Information(); // Image Information
        public virtual Bitmap Unpack(ref Stream data, Stream palette) // Unpack image (with external palette file)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```